# How i can i get header from response as ServletResponse().getHeader(string) is not visible?

Tags: java, servlets

i have successfully set the httpServletResponse().setHeader("custtype", "permanent") but when i try to retrieve it httpServletResponse().getHeader("custtype")  i do not see getheader method when i do control + soace in eclipse but as per doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html its there. I am not sure why getHeader method is not visible here in eclipse.?

How i can i get header from response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**getHeaders(...) methods HttpServletResponse are supported since Servlet 3.0.**, Before this version you can find only setHeader(...) methods.

For earlier version you can try wrapping the response and implement storing the headers in your wrapper class.

Comment: My Eclipse has compiler compliance of Java 1.6, and my project has 'Dynamic Web Module' Facet at version 3.0... any idea why Eclipse still indicates there's no `setHeader()` on javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse ?

Comment: How can that be done, could you show us a small example?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader(java.lang.String) says:

> Since: Servlet 3.0

`setHeader` was added in Servlet 3.0. Perhaps your Eclipse instance is using documentation for an earlier version.

Comment: if set header is visible then get header should also be visible right?i am using jre 6.

Comment: No, not necessarily. Why should it have to be symmetrical? In the documents it doesn't put a "since" for `setHeader` while `getHeader` clearly starts from Servlet 3.0. Setting headers in a response is more common than reading headers that were set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the earlier version of Java. `getHeader(String)` has been added since its version 3.0. If you want to add it, upgrade your Java version.

Comment: Has nothing to do with version of Java, but the Servlet spec, which is versioned independently of Java.

Answer (score -1):

`HttpServletResponse.getHeader()` function is available in `HttpServletResponse` class.

Comment: The OP is using that class, what point/value is your answer adding or clarifying?