# How i can i get header from HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

1. List item

How can I get the header information from HttpServletResponse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172064/how-i-can-i-get-header-from-response-as-servletresponse-getheaderstring-is-n

Comment: This question should never have achieved such a high ranking on google, 4 years later.

Answer (score 4):

There is a method in that [getHeader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29)

Note:Available only for **servelt 3.0**,If not you can't use this.

and

> This method considers only response headers set or added via setHeader(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), addHeader(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), setDateHeader(java.lang.String, long), addDateHeader(java.lang.String, long), setIntHeader(java.lang.String, int), or addIntHeader(java.lang.String, int), respectively.

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I have added maven dependency javax.servlet Version 3.1 now I am able to resolve compilation error on JSP, but I am not able to get HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest object in controller. I am using Spring Spring MVC annotation based

Comment: @KrishnaKumar  I am not much aware of Spring: You need make some changes in your method signature I guess see here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller

Answer (score 1):

HttpServletResponse.getHeader("key")   returns first value

HttpServletResponse.getHeaders("key)  return all values belonging to this key.

Answer (score 0):

The [HttpServletResponse.getHeaders method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) is almost certainly what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpServletResponse#getHeaders(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) returns you a list of all headers for that string value

Comment: Hi Philipp, getting compilation error when using <% response.getHeader("Author"); %> May this is because of I am using maven dependency javax.servlet - version 2.5